# Operador ">" não pode ser usando comparando strings

Tags: java, string, operadores

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ordenarNomes{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String [] nomes = new String [20];

        for(int i=0;i<nomes.length;i++){
            System.out.println("Informe os nomes: ");
            nomes[i] = in.next();
        }
        String x = " ";
        for(int i=1;i<nomes.length-1;i++){
            for(int j=i+1;j<nomes.length;j++){
                if(nomes[i] > nomes[j]){
                    x = nomes[i];
                    nomes[i] = nomes[j];
                    nomes[j] = x;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<nomes.length;i++){
            System.out.print(nomes[i]+" ");
        }
    }    
}
```

Gerando o seguinte erro:

> The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s)

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Em Java `String` não é um tipo de primeira classe, então ele não tem operadores, e você deve comparar com o método [`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class OrdenarNomes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[] nomes = new String[20];
        for (int i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Informe os nomes: ");
            nomes[i] = in.next();
        }
        String x = " ";
        for (int i = 0; i < nomes.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nomes.length; j++) {
                if (nomes[i].compareTo(nomes[j]) > 0) {
                    x = nomes[i];
                    nomes[i] = nomes[j];
                    nomes[j] = x;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < nomes.length; i++) System.out.print(nomes[i]+" ");
    }    
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/zFsEOu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/CompareStrings). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/String/Compare.java).

Tinha mais erros

Comment: No último `for` vi que retirou as chaves, é somente estético ou há algo a mais (melhor performance, por exemplo)?